# Search for Either True-False or non Existing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

I have some docs in libraries with bool "somebool". Then I can search "somebool=true" which delivers the set.

However the majority of docs (with the same content type) in most libraries do not have this column "somebool".

So I want (the ones that have this column + this column must be true) AND (everything else that does not have this column). Is there a search query to additionally have something for the existence of a column ?

Comment: Hmm, after trying this out a lot I'm not sure it is possible. Would it be possible for you to "invert" what your boolean field does? So that you can do an `somebool<>1` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on "the outside" crawling different farms owned by different departments, so have no influence on their configurations.